# Error for python

Tags: python

Ok i have an if then statement and i want it to display something if the user clicks Yes or No and if they enter something except YES OR NO then it gives an error. But when i do it, i put it in a print variable but even though they put something else it still goes on. Here is the code.

```
drink = raw_input("Do you want a drink?")
if (drink =="Yes" or drink =="yes"):
    print ("Soda\n Coffee \n Latte\n or Smoothie")
    drink1 = raw_input("What type of drink will you like?")
    print (drink1," coming up")
else:
    print ("Error")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your condition only has a condition for `yes`. So even if you take `no` as input, you will still go in to the error condition. You need an extra `elif` to handle the "no" case.

Also, just cast `drink` to lower and always check it for one case: "yes":

```
drink = raw_input("Do you want a drink?").lower()
if (drink == "yes"):
    print ("Soda\n Coffee \n Latte\n or Smoothie")
    drink1 = raw_input("What type of drink will you like?")
    print (drink1," coming up")
elif (drink == "no"):
    print("you do not want a drink")
    # do things for no here
else:
    print ("Error")
```

Comment: what does the ".lower" do lol. Sorry we haven't learned that yet in class

Comment: `.lower` converts all the letters to lowercase in a specified string.

Comment: ^^Yup. That would be it.

Comment: so its redundant to put like (blah =="yes" or blah=="Yes")

Comment: If you copy pasted my code to run it, then you will most definitely get an error. You need to put code inside the `elif (drink.lower() == "no"):` condition

Comment: actually i put it under that condition with print ("Error")

Comment: @Jon2713 I think using `lower()` in every conditional statement is a bit redundant. You can try doing this instead:
    
`drink = raw_input("Do you want a drink?").lower()`
    
That would convert the letters of your input to lowercase immediately after inputting.

Comment: @SeanBallais You're absolutely right. Silly mistake. I corrected my solution. Thanks.